# Can I choose files for a merge based just on the most recently changed?

Tags: git, merge

One of my projects uses git for history but merging files from different branches is impractical. In this situation, if the same file has been changed in multiple branches, then a "merge" means to use the most recently changed file as the desired file going forward.

Can this be automated in Git?

Comment: You might be able to manually do it using an "ours" recursive merge strategy option for `merge`, or something like that. If you wanted to "automate" that, there might be another option that `merge` has so that it "remembers" what merge strategy you want to use for a particular file, or a merge configuration if not an option. There are probably a few questions like that that have been asked already on Stack Overflow, if you want to spend time digging around for them.

Comment: I did a little searching but without knowing the right keywords such as "ours" (which is new to me), it's hard to find stuff. I'll look into this. Thanks

Comment: I might go and look for the right Stack Overflow questions someday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of git's merge drivers can do this, and unless the needed timestamp can be found by looking in the data itself I don't see how to write a custom merge driver to do it either.  Git intentionally doesn't preserve metadata (beyond the execute bit); merge drivers are given the left-branch content, the right-branch content, and the original content to work with.  If the commit-date or author-date on the commit that changed the file rather than on the file itself when committed is enough you could probably cook up some resolution assists based on (keyboard-to-editbox sketch) `git log --format='%h %at %s' HEAD MERGE_HEAD -- path/to/file|sort -nrk2|sed 's/ .*//;q'|xargs -I@ git checkout @ -- path/to/file`.

Comment: Yes, I should have said the most recently changed (AND COMMITTED) file. Seems to me a feature like this would be very useful for certain kinds of files (images, audio being the obvious examples) where you generally just want the latest version

Comment: I can't find any simple way to achieve this, and I'm not sure I could make anything that would be enough better than the helper above, just on maintainability alone.